# How to modify new Date Picker in SwiftUI?

Tags: datepicker, swiftui

In the last update of SwiftUI, there we have got a couple of new DatePicker styles. I was trying to modify the default appearance of DatePicker. However could not find a way to do so.

[image]

This is the default view right now. I would like to resize the button and also would like to change the background colour (like making it completely transparent).
Could any one please suggest a proper way to do these modification?

Comment: This hackingwithswift tutorial may help (updated for ios14): https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-create-a-date-picker-and-read-values-from-it

Comment: This tutorial doesn't help for this case I think. I have tried it. I want to modify the above button shown in the picture. Thanks Lemon